# Why is my DLL getting so big? .NET

Tags: .net, optimization, dll

I'm writing a test library for some router and it's getting bigger and bigger. The compiled version is now 130 MB, which seems scary big too me. It also becomes very inconvenient to handle.

I'm working with .NET 3.5 and VS2010.

There are only 10 References, 7 System, log4net and 2 company DLLs. All code files add up to 239 KB.

There is virtually no difference if I compile to DEBUG or RELEASE or of I check "Optimzie Code"

I could split the DLL to various projects, but most of the could is used in all projects.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Open it in dotPeek or Reflector and see what's inside. If it's that big, I suspect you have some bloated embedded resources.

Comment: May be you have some embedded resources?

Comment: damn you guys are right, someone (really not me!) added the lib itself as resource, so it build on itself with each compile

Comment: I had a similar problem in .NET 4.8 and it turned out that it was a load of Entity Framework migration files - after I deleted those, it went from 70MB to 4!